# The name "ViewModelLocator" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ComEX.ViewModel"

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

VS 2013.  Trying to learn MVVM and commands in WPF, but I can't see why I am getting this error.

"The name "ViewModelLocator" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ComEX.ViewModel"."

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZa3E.jpg)

```
<Application x:Class="ComEX.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ComEX.ViewModel"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             mc:Ignorable="d ignore">

    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Global View Model Locator-->
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                             d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Comment: You should have namespace : clr-namespace  with a class :ComEX  and an object in the class : ViewModel.  ViewModel should also have an object ViewModelLocator.

Comment: Is your `ViewModelLocator` class in the namespace `ComEX.ViewModel`? Maybe paste the first lines after `namespace` in that file for more help.

Comment: Not sure what was wrong, it compiles now with no errors.

Answer (score 4):

There are two workarounds to solve this issue

1. Try to right click on solution and after that choose in pop up menu "Clean" or "Clean solution" and after that "Rebuild"

If this did not help try second:

2. Such error also hapens if an exception occurred while creating instances registered in locator by SimpleIoc.Default.Register, so try to fix all errors except locator related and this error will also disapear